# jQuery .find() problem

Tags: jquery, find

My problem is the following, I use jquery to get div content but .find() return null.

We can view the source code here: http://webdevs-bg.net/web/html5pload/js.html and open your console to view the log from find().

Comment: I don't see anything in the console.

Comment: open console and click of link JSинг and when u are in JSинг click Начало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is returning an entire HTML document. Don't do that. You'll have trouble traversing it because different browsers behave differently when dropping an entire document into a jQuery object.

A temporary fix may be to use the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method instead of `.find()`.

I'm guessing you're testing on a browser that strips out everything but the content of the `<body>`, leaving the `"#content"` element at the top level where `.find()` can't locate it.

Note that this won't work in all browsers, which is why you'd need to only return the content you actually want.

Also, you're appending a new element with `#content` to an existing element on the page with the same ID. I assume you'd only want to append its children.

```
$.get(History.getState().url, {
    text: "123"
},

function (response) {     //   v--filter will work in some browsers, but not all
    var $content = $response.filter("#content"); 
    $("#content").empty().append($content); // <-- appending #content to #content?
    console.log('content is: ', $content);
});
```

This should be your response:

```
<h3> JS файл </h3>
```

...but instead you sent this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history/amplify.store.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.adapter.jquery.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="history/history.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
        padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>

        <script>
            var History = window.History;
            $(function() {
            History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange', function() {
            $.get(History.getState().url, {text: "123"}, 

            function(response) {
            var $response = $(response);
            var $content = $response.find("#content");
            $("#content").empty().append($content);
            console.log($content);

            });
            });
            $("a").click(function() {
            History.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr("href"));
            return false;
            });
            });
        </script>
        <a href="ffmpeg.php">Начало</a> | <a href="js.html">JSинг</a>
        <div id="content">
            <h3> JS файл </h3>  <!-- <<--THIS should be your response -->
        </div>
        <div id="c2">footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```